# Как в js, сделать так что бы объект не был связан со своим предшественником

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, объекты

Есть проблема, я в цикле иду по объектам и делаю так `let a = objects[i];`, после я пытаюсь добавить новые свойства `a.new = '1';` но оно у всех объектов которые получаются в результате этого цикла одинаковы (если что a.new везде разные значения а не 1). Как это решить?

Comment: let же не даёт переобъявлять переменную. Попробуйте вынести за цикл `let a;`, а в цикле `a = objects[i];`.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: Лучше бы вы привели в вопросе ваш код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let же не даёт переобъявлять переменную. Попробуйте вынести за цикл let a;, а в цикле a = objects[i];